# How to prove that a number is prime using Znumtheory in Coq

Tags: primes, coq

I'm trying to prove that a number is prime using the Znumtheory library.

In Znumtheory primes are defined in terms of relative primes:

```
  Inductive prime (p:Z) : Prop :=
      prime_intro :
      1 < p -> (forall n:Z, 1 <= n < p -> rel_prime n p) -> prime p.
```

So to prove that 3 is prime I should apply prime_intro to the goal. Here is my try:

```
Theorem prime3 : prime 3.
Proof.
    apply prime_intro.

  - omega.
  - intros. 
    unfold rel_prime. apply Zis_gcd_intro.
    + apply Z.divide_1_l.
    + apply Z.divide_1_l.
    + intros. Abort.
```

I don't know how to use the hypothesis `H : 1 <= n < 3` which says that `n` is `1` or `2`. I could destruct it, apply `lt_eq_cases` and destruct it again, but I would be stuck with a useless `1 < n` in the first case.

I wasn't expecting to have a hard time with something that looks so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lemma you mentioned is actually proved in that library, under the name `prime_3`.  You can look up its proof on [GitHub](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/master/theories/ZArith/Znumtheory.v).

You mentioned how strange it is to have such a hard time to prove something so simple. Indeed, the proof in the standard library is quite complicated. Luckily, there are much better ways to work out this result.  The [Mathematical Components](https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp) library advocates for a different style of development based on boolean properties.  There, `prime` is not an inductively defined predicate, but a function `nat -> bool` that checks whether its argument is prime.  Because of this, we can prove such simple facts by computation:

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrbool ssrnat prime.

Lemma prime_3 : prime 3. Proof. reflexivity. Qed.
```

There is a bit of magic going on here: the library declares a coercion `is_true : bool -> Prop` that is automatically inserted whenever a boolean is used in a place where a proposition is expected.  It is defined as follows:

```
Definition is_true (b : bool) : Prop := b = true.
```

Thus, what `prime_3` really is proving above is `prime 3 = true`, which is what makes that simple proof possible.

The library allows you to connect this boolean notion of what a prime number is to a more conventional one via a *reflection lemma*:

```
Lemma primeP p :
  reflect (p > 1 /\ forall d, d %| p -> xpred2 1 p d) (prime p).
```

Unpacking notations and definitions, what this statement says is that `prime p` equals `true` if and only if `p > 1` and every `d` that divides `p` is equal to `1` or `p`.  I am afraid it would be a lengthy detour to explain how this reflection lemma works exactly, but if you find this interesting I strongly encourage you to look up more about Mathematical Components.

Comment: That answer is quite surprising. For some seconds I thought that I was  idiot. Your answer didn't prove that I'm not, but showed that this is hard even for non-idiot people. I will take a look in this other library, thanks for telling me about it. PS: Eu fico muito esperançoso ao ver um brasileiro como você!

Comment: @RafaelCastro Fico feliz que tenha podido ajudar!

Answer (score 3):

I have a variant of @larsr's proof.

```
Require Import ZArith.
Require Import Znumtheory.
Require Import Omega.

Theorem prime3 : prime 3.
Proof.
  constructor.
  - omega.
  - intros.
    assert (n = 1 \/ n = 2) as Ha by omega.
    destruct Ha; subst n; apply Zgcd_is_gcd.
Qed.
```

Like @larsr's proof, we prove that `1 < 3` using `omega` and then prove that either `n=1` or `n=2` using `omega` again.

To prove `rel_prime 1 3` and `rel_prime 2 3` which are defined in terms of `Zis_gcd`, we apply `Zgcd_is_gcd`. This lemma states that computing the `gcd` is enough. This is trivial on concrete inputs like `(1,3)` and `(2,3)`.

**EDIT**: We can generalize this result, using only Gallina. We define a boolean function `is_prime` that we prove correct w.r.t. the inductive specification `prime`. I guess this can be done in a more elegant way, but I am confused with all the lemmas related to `Z`. Moreover, some of the definitions are opaque and cannot be used (at least directly) to define a computable function.

```
Require Import ZArith.
Require Import Znumtheory.
Require Import Omega.
Require Import Bool.
Require Import Recdef.

(** [for_all] checks that [f] is true for any integer between 1 and [n] *)
Function for_all (f:Z->bool) n {measure Z.to_nat n}:=
  if n <=? 1 then true
  else f (n-1) && for_all f (n-1).
Proof.
  intros.
  apply Z.leb_nle in teq.
  apply Z2Nat.inj_lt. omega. omega. omega.
Defined.

Lemma for_all_spec : forall f n,
  for_all f n = true -> forall k, 1 <= k < n -> f k = true.
Proof.
  intros.
  assert (0 <= n) by omega.
  revert n H1 k H0 H.
  apply (natlike_ind (fun n => forall k : Z, 1 <= k < n ->
         for_all f n = true -> f k = true)); intros.
  - omega.
  - rewrite for_all_equation in H2.
    destruct (Z.leb_spec0 (Z.succ x) 1).
    + omega.
    + replace (Z.succ x - 1) with x in H2 by omega. apply andb_true_iff in H2.
      assert (k < x \/ k = x) by omega.
      destruct H3.
      * apply H0. omega. apply H2.
      * subst k. apply H2.
Qed.

Definition is_prime (p:Z) :=
  (1 <? p) && for_all (fun k => Z.gcd k p =? 1) p.

Theorem is_prime_correct : forall z, is_prime z = true -> prime z.
Proof.
  intros. unfold is_prime in H.
  apply andb_true_iff in H. destruct H as (H & H0).
  constructor.
  - apply Z.ltb_lt. assumption.
  - intros.
    apply for_all_spec with (k:=n) in H0; try assumption.
    unfold rel_prime. apply Z.eqb_eq in H0. rewrite <- H0.
    apply Zgcd_is_gcd.
Qed.
```

The proof becomes nearly as simple as @Arthur's one.

```
Theorem prime113 : prime 113.
Proof.
  apply is_prime_correct; reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof that I think is quite understandable as one steps through it.
It stays at the level of number theory and doesn't unfold definitions that much.  I put in some comments, don't know if it makes it more or less readable.  But try to step through it in the IDE, if you care for it...

```
Require Import ZArith.
Require Import Znumtheory.

Inductive prime (p:Z) : Prop :=
      prime_intro :
      1 < p -> (forall n:Z, 1 <= n < p -> rel_prime n p) -> prime p.

Require Import Omega.

Theorem prime3 : prime 3.
Proof.
  constructor.
  omega.                    (* prove 1 < 3 *)
  intros; constructor.      (* prove rel_prime n 3 *)
  exists n. omega.          (* prove (1 | n) *)
  exists 3. omega.          (* prove (1 | 3) *)

  (* our goal is now (x | 1), and we know (x | n) and (x | 3) *)
  assert (Hn: n=1 \/ n=2) by omega; clear H. (* because 1 <= n < 3 *)
  case Hn.                  (* consider cases n=1 and n=2 *)
  - intros; subst; trivial. (* case n = 1: proves (x | 1) because we know (x | n) *)
  - intros; subst.          (* case n = 2: we know (x | n) and (x | 3) *)
    assert (Hgcd: (x | Z.gcd 2 3)) by (apply Z.gcd_greatest; trivial).
    (* Z.gcd_greatest: (x | 2) -> x | 3) -> (x | Z.gcd 2 3) *)
    apply Hgcd. (* prove (x | 1), because Z.gcd 2 3 = 1 *)
Qed.
```

Comment: I didn't know that omega can prove n=1 \/ n=2 with that assumptions. Other trick step was using gcd 2 3 to prove (x | 1).

Answer (score 1):

Fun fact: @epoiner's answer can be used together with Ltac in a proof script for any prime number.

```
Theorem prime113 : prime 113.
Proof.
  constructor.
  - omega.
  - intros n H;
    repeat  match goal with | H : 1 <= ?n < ?a  |- _ =>
       assert (Hn: n = a -1 \/ 1 <= n < a - 1) by omega;
       clear H; destruct Hn as [Hn | H];
       [subst n; apply Zgcd_is_gcd | simpl in H; try omega ]
    end.
Qed.
```

However, the proof term gets unwieldy, and checking becomes slower and slower.  This is why it small scale reflection (ssreflect) where computation is moved into the type checking probably is preferrable in the long run.  It's hard to beat @Arthur Azevedo De Amorim's proof:
`Proof. reflexivity. Qed.` :-) Both in terms of computation time, and memory-wise.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a proof for any prime number, but not relying on Ltac like yours. And btw, it's eponier, not epoiner.